# How do I add a method to a function?

Tags: javascript

Specifically, how can I write prototypes that allow chaining, such as the following:

```
$('myDiv').html('Hello World').fadeIn('slow');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the appropriate stuff from the functions. The basic rule of thumb is take any method that would normaly return nothing and make it return `this` instead.

```
function Constructor(){};

Constructor.prototype = {
    foo: function(){
        console.log('foo');
        return this;
    },
    bar: function(x){
        console.log('bar', x);
        return this;
    }
}

var obj = new Constructor();
obj.foo().bar(17).bar(42).foo();
```

Answer (score 5):

The technique you're describing is called [fluent interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface), and it involves returning the same kind of object from all chainable functions.  That object's prototype contains the function definitions.

The linked article includes example code in various languages, including javascript.

Answer (score 1):

In that particular situation, each method returns `this`. So:

```
// ... this has to be the most impractical class I've ever written, but it is a
// great illustration of the point.
var returner = new function() {
    this.returnThis = function(){
        console.log("returning");
        return this
     }
 }
 var ret2 = returner.returnThis().returnThis().
           returnThis().returnThis() // logs "returning" four times.

 console.log( ret2 == returner ) // true
```

Answer (score 1):

Chaining example:

```
var avatar = function() {

    this.turnLeft = function {
       // some logic here
       return this;
    }

    this.turnRight = function {
       // some logic here
       return this;
    }

    this.pickUpItem = function {
       // some logic here
       return this;
    }

};


var frodo = new avatar();
frodo.turnLeft().turnRight().pickUpItem();
```